# Total Commander Ultima Prime: how to change Create New Folder (F7) popup window position?

Tags: file-management, total-commander

I am using an amazing tool - Total Commander Ultima Prime. But in the recent version 7.6, when I open a popup to create a new folder (by pressing <kbd>F7</kbd>), the popup shows up just between my two screens (so each screen displays half of the popup :) ).

[image: Create New Folder (F7) popup window]

How to change the default <kbd>F7</kbd> popup position?

(No, plugging in the third screen is not a solution).

Comment: You're using Total Commander Ultima Prime which seems to be a kind of "extended edition" of Total Commander. The current version of Total Commander would be 9.22a and there was no version 7.6 according to their history. The placement of that dialog is likely due to one of the extensions that's included.

Comment: In my own Total Commander (I am at V9.22a), The F7 pop-up lands at the right edge of the left window of Total Commander. The pop-up stays entirely within the Total Commander overall window

Comment: This is **not** Total Commander. [From their site](https://tcup.pl/index.php/en/): *Total Commander Ultima Prime 

is a collection of the software and customized settings sets gathered in one installation package for enhancing Total Commander (file manager) possibilities. Our project differs from official distribution provided by Christian Ghisler on www.totalcmd.com site.*